# Ceasar cipher: python

Tags: python, encryption

The decrypting section doesn't work  because it would randomly put the wrong letters which doesn't make `enter code here`the word that was encrypted in the first place. For example if I encrypted 'hello' by 7 the encryption would be 'olssv' but when I decrypted that it would become 'cebbe'

I think the problem is on line 22 ' `cipher2 += alphabet[(alphabet.index(A)-key)%len(cipher)]`' but I'm not 100% sure.

Here is my code.

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
La = len(alphabet)
message = input("Insert your message: ")
key = int(input("Insert your key: "))
cipher = ''

for A in message:
    if A in alphabet:
        cipher += alphabet[(alphabet.index(A)+key)%La]
    else:
        print ("Error")
print(cipher)

cipher2 = ''

question = input("Do you wish to decrypt? Y/N: ")

if question.lower() == 'y':
    for A in cipher:
        if A in alphabet:
            print((cipher.index(A)-key))
        cipher2 += alphabet[(alphabet.index(A)-key)%len(cipher)]
    else:
          print(cipher2)
else:
    print("Thank you")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparing your two lines:

```
     cipher += alphabet[(alphabet.index(A)+key)%La]
    cipher2 += alphabet[(alphabet.index(A)-key)%len(cipher)]
```

Aside from the expected difference in addition/subtraction, it looks like you're also changing what you're using for modulus. Try sticking with `La` for both.

```
    cipher += alphabet[(alphabet.index(A)+key)%La]
    cipher2 += alphabet[(alphabet.index(A)-key)%La]
```